# how to make decision on excel in Apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

i have a excel workbook coming from a nifi flow and a JSON coming from different flow.I want to match the content of JSON with first sheet of excel workbook and if its true then pass the workbook forward otherwise destroy it. i am not getting the logic of doing it and also there are no custom processor available for it. some small help will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the workbook is simple enough, you could try to parse it as CSV or raw XML and perform content extraction on it to compare with the JSON. You can also use an `ExecuteScript` processor with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), which allows full-featured Microsoft Excel reading/writing to perform the content extraction and comparison.